# How do I extract this switch widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a StatefulWidget with a ListView, the ListView has the bunch of switches with text next to them.
Now i want to extract this into a custom switch widget because i have this more than once.
I don't know how to do this, also I need to know inside my parent widget what state each switch has.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Text("Use custom dhcp server"),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
        child: Switch(
          value: _dhcp,
          activeColor: Colors.blue,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              _dhcp = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own stateless widget like this:

```
class CustomSwitch extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomSwitch({
    Key key,
    @required this.value,
    @required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool value;
  final void Function(bool) onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
      value: value,
      activeColor: Colors.blue,
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Where you can use it anywhere like this:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  bool switchValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        CustomSwitch(
          value: switchValue,
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              switchValue = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```